# Why does this script runs improperly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So sorry for my carelessness....the second version runs properly now.

But I am still confused with the first issue:

```
#!/bin/bash

for((i=1;i<=50;i++))
do
sum=$((sum+i))
done
echo $sum
```

Then sh 6.sh:

[image]

Why could this happen...

Since the original version was rewritten, I cannot reproduce this issue too...What may cause that issue?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin  Do you mean my code runs correctly on your computer?

Comment: @Delibz: Please copy paste your code into http://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix all the errors before posting into SO to save us all from trivial issues and make the community more useful.

Comment: @Delibz Yep, it does.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. Please run it as `sh -xv 6.sh` and show the result

Comment: Don't edit your post to ask a different question than the one solved by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your `for` line. It seems it has mix of `i`, `l` and `1`. Please try this:

```
 for((i=1;i<50;i++))
```

Comment: OMG....what a stupid question...  thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I copied and pasted the original code and it works with no issues.

Comment: @Maxim Yes, I did the same with the same result. The question was about the new code.